# How to find SPS and PPS string in H264 codec from mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, codec, libavcodec, smooth-streaming

As you all know that in Smooth Stream client manifest file, contains a "CodecPrivateData" attribute in video tag. Now after my initial investigation I found that this string is formed by using SPS and PPS which are essentially NAL units.

I am looking for a way to extract that information from video GOP, so that I can use the same to create manifest file and manually substitute codec private data

Basically, i am looking forward to create custom app to create smooth representation using ffmpeg

Comment: Just to clarify, so you want to use ffmpeg to extract SPS and PPS from an .mp4 container programatically or this is a one time extraction of SPS/PPS from a single .mp4 file?

Comment: well to be honest ffmpeg is just an option, I would be ok if any other tool is also available which can help me in getting SPS/PPS from mp4.Regarding your question, not sure if i understand it correctly. But I am ok with anyway, I just need to extract SPS and PPS from mp4

Answer (score 15):

Note that SPS/PPS are stored separately from video track in the mp4 file in one of the global headers(avcC portion of the global header).

Here is format:
 8+ bytes per ISO/IEC 14496-10

```
                 = long unsigned offset + long ASCII text string 'avcC'
                -> 1 byte version = 8-bit hex version  (current = 1)
                -> 1 byte H.264 profile = 8-bit unsigned stream profile
                -> 1 byte H.264 compatible profiles = 8-bit hex flags
                -> 1 byte H.264 level = 8-bit unsigned stream level
                -> 1 1/2 nibble reserved = 6-bit unsigned value set to 63
                -> 1/2 nibble NAL length = 2-bit length byte size type
                  - 1 byte = 0 ; 2 bytes = 1 ; 4 bytes = 3
                -> 1 byte number of SPS = 8-bit unsigned total
                -> 2+ bytes SPS length = short unsigned length
                -> + SPS NAL unit = hexdump
                -> 1 byte number of PPS = 8-bit unsigned total
                -> 2+ bytes PPS length = short unsigned length
                -> + PPS NAL unit = hexdump
```

If you just want to extract SPS/PPS from a single .mp4, you can use hex editor and get the SPS/PPS by inspection based on the MP4 format specs above(look for "avcC" string by searching from the end of the file); and then add the SPS/PPS bytes to an c-style array for your use.

Otherwise you can use ffmpeg together with [h264bitstream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/h264bitstream/) utility to extract SPS/PPS. First run ffmpeg on the command line to extract h264 stream:

```
ffmpeg -i my_funny_video.mp4 -vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -an my_funny_video.h264
```

Then run h264_analyze from the h264bitstream utility:

```
h264_analyze my_funny_video.h264
```

which will product a detailed analysis on your SPS/PPS and other NALs.

Comment: I am not sure how can I use ffmpeg to extract SPS/PPS? It will be huge favour if you can guide on that too?

Comment: Also I am able to trace the SPS and PPS using C#, But after analyizing I found that PPS / SPS string length can vary depending on video. Do they follow any pattern